# PHP: How to get <br/> working in a simplexml_load_file() var

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am loading an xml in php via simplexml_load_file().

I load the file with that:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('flash/datas/datas.xml');
```

And the access my content like that:

```
$descText = $xml->aboutModule->chocolaterie->desc
```

The text from desc is well registred in my $descText, but all the `<br/>` of the text disappear... So my long text is on a single line, not so good :-/

Do you know how to solve that? Is there a special traitement to do one the `$xml` var? Or someting else?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Recommendation: Read this: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/NamespaceTutorial/Output/index.html or this: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html and realize, that your XHTML starts with this: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to make it work.

### The right one

Do *not* store those `<br/>`. Store the real actual newlines, e.g.

```
<desc>
    Line 1.
    Line 2.
</desc>
```

Then use nl2br() to replace newlines with HTML tags. This is assuming your description does not normally contain markup. If it does, use CDATA sections as proposed in another answer.

### The *other* one

```
$descText = strip_tags($xml->aboutModule->chocolaterie->desc->asXML(), '<br /><br/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look of [this](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-file.php#71667).

*There is a way to get back HTML tags. For example:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<intro>
    Welcome to <b>Example.com</b>!
</intro>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
// I use @ so that it doesn't spit out content of my XML in an
// error message if the load fails. The content could be
// passwords so this is just to be safe.
$xml = @simplexml_load_file('content_intro.xml');
if ($xml) {
    // asXML() will keep the HTML tags but it will also keep the parent tag <intro> so I strip them out with a str_replace. You could obviously also use a preg_replace if you have lots of tags.
    $intro = str_replace(array('<intro>', '</intro>'), '', $xml->asXML());
} else {
    $error = "Could not load intro XML file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help!
It work perfectly, even with just the ->asXML() command. 

I am amazed to discover that stack overflow isn't any urban legend! So fast answsers, thank very much to you all!

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over your source XML, you may find it better to store the description as character data, i.e. in a CDATA wrapper, rather than mixing your XML with HTML.

For example, instead of:

```
...
<desc>
    This is a description<br /> with a break in it
</desc>
...
```

...do something like:

```
...
<desc>
<![CDATA[
    This is a description<br /> with a break in it
]]>
</desc>
```

But if you haven't, then as Casidiablo says, you'll have to grab the content of the `<desc>` element as XML.

Comment: Yeah, I wholeheartedly agree that mixing HTML with XML = bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use the following code to replace the BR tags to new line chars.

`preg_replace("/(\s*)+/", "\n", $input);`

OR

you can convert the description content to "htmlentities" and then turn back to "htmlspecialchars"